# Auto-enable button according to condition

Tags: swift3

Let's say I have 2 classes, `A` and `B`, where `B` is an attribute of `A`.

`A` is a ViewController and contains a button (called `but`).

`B` contains an array (called `arr`).

I want `A.but` to be disabled always `B.arr` is empty and enabled when `B.arr` is not empty anymore.

Is there a good way for the button to keep track of this and auto-enable/disable itself?

---

I could set initially `A.but` disabled and update it (if necessary) on `B.arr didSet`, but I'm searching for a solution that doesn't look like a workaround

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One approach could be to use a `Delegate` pattern. This would allow you to expose delegate methods that would be called whenever something is added or removed from the `Array`. Your `ViewController` can then conform to your `Delegate` protocol and manage the enabled state of your button.

**Example:**

> MyArrayDelegate.swift

```
protocol MyArrayDelegate: class {
    func didChange(_ myArray: MyArray)
}
```

> MyArray.swift

```
class MyArray {
    weak var delegate: MyArrayDelegate?

    private var _myArray = [Int]()
    var myArray: [Int] {
        return _myArray
    }

    func append(_ element: Int) {
        _myArray.append(element)
        delegate?.didChange(self)
    }

    func remove(at index: Int) -> Int {
        let element = _myArray.remove(at: index)
        delegate?.didChange(self)

        return element
    }
}
```

`append(_:)` and `remove(at:)` just wrap the standard `Array` methods.

> ViewController.swift

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, MyArrayDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var myButton: UIButton!

    private var myArray = MyArray()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        myArray.delegate = self
        myButton.isEnabled = false
    }

    @IBAction func buttonTapped(_ sender: Any) {
        print(myArray.myArray.count)
    }

    @IBAction func addButtonTapped(_ sender: Any) {
        myArray.append(1)
    }

    @IBAction func removeButtonTapped(_ sender: Any) {
        if myArray.myArray.count > 0 {
            _ = myArray.remove(at: 0)
        }
    }

    func didChange(_ myArray: MyArray) {
        if myArray.myArray.count > 0 {
            myButton.isEnabled = true
        } else {
            myButton.isEnabled = false
        }
    }
}
```

`didChange(_:)` will get called whenever the `append(_:)` or `remove(at:)` methods are called on a `MyArray` instance.

> Example User Interface

[image]

Initially the "Button" is disabled. When you tap "+", it will become enabled. If you continue to tap "+", the "Button" will remain enabled. If you tap "Remove", one element will be removed from the array. If all of the elements are removed from the array, then the "Button" will become disabled.